# align a paragraph

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a simple question using html and css... hopefully someone can help me to have a "duh" moment.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanfrancy/4t2N9/3/).

I'm planning on having event dates on the left and event information on the right side, wanting a two column look... and with what I have right now, the information wraps around to the beginning, aligning itself with the date. I want the info to align.

I know I can easily accomplish this either with a div-float or using a table, but I don't want either of those. Maybe I'm using the wrong elements.. not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the problem with using a floating element?

Comment: I guess nothing, I just don't want a different div for each event. How can I use float and not have extra markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an alternative solution](http://jsfiddle.net/4t2N9/15/), using a `dl`, but it assumes that you have `.clearfix` included in your styles.

HTML:

```
<dl id="container" class="clearfix">
    <dt>05/31/12</dt>
    <dd>The first event looks like this. It has to wrap around.</dd>
    <dt>06/01/12</dt>
    <dd>The second event looks like this. It has to wrap around too.</dd>
    <dt>06/01/12</dt>
    <dd>Thesecondeventlookslikethis.Ithastowraparoundtoo.</dd> 
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
dl#container{
    width:270px;
    background-color:#e9cfa7;
}

dt{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:25%; 
    margin-right:2%;
    background-color:#5d396e;
}

dd{
    width:70%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    }

.clearfix {display: inline-block;}  /* for IE/Mac */
```

Comment: I just realized that you'll need a little extra css to stop long strings from breaking this. See my update.

Comment: Works great, but can it just highlight the words, rather than the whole dt?

Comment: Not without adding in a span or another element to target it more closely.

Comment: I went ahead and added a span to it to make it just the text. Just so you know what it was for... http://bit.ly/LKU6c2. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks good! I think you can get that without the span, and removing the width on the `dt`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a negative `text-indent` coupled with a `margin-left` of the same amount:

```
#container p {
    text-indent: -4em;
    margin-left: 4em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4t2N9/4/).

Comment: This works, but it will only be a fixed width (4em), correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS in your fiddle:

```
#container {
    width: 270px;
    background: #e9cfa7;
}
#container p:not(span) { padding-left: 70px }
#container p span {
    background-color: #5d396e;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -70px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#container p {position: relative; padding: 0 4px 4px 80px;}

#container p span {background-color: #5d396e; color: #FFF;  display:block; width: 60px;position: absolute; left: 4px; top: 4px; padding: 4px}
```